# Vue js: change CSS with v-if and v-else statment

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my Vue JS project i wanted to show data from API and its working good, my only problem is when i showed `{{flat.status}}` below in my code i wanted to play with CSS for ex: if status==Available let text color be green , and when status==Sold let text color be red and etc ..

is there a way to do it?

```js
<b-th v-for="(flat, index) in Building.flats" :key="index" >
               <p> {{flat.status}} </p>
</b-th>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can do this in a few ways, but the simplest is just to use conditional styles tags. In the `:style`, just write code!

```
<p :style=flat.status === 'available' ? 'color: green;' : 'color: 'red'>{{ flat.status }}</p>
```

If you'd like more CSS control, just use conditional classes.

```
<p :class="flat.status === 'available' ? 'text-green' : 'text-red'>{{ flat.status }}</p>

<style>
.text-green {
  // CSS here
}
</style>
```

There are other [class binding styles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) you can look into for more information. They will give you other ways to do all this as well.

For multiple classes (similar example in the link I provided):

```
<div :class="{ 'text-green': flat.available, 'text-red': flat.sold, 'text-yellow': flat.booked }">{{ flat.name }}</div>
```

Comment: I know this is should work perfectly as it is, but what if they had more than two status? What if we add more status after deployment ? what if the designer need to change the color ?
I advice to add a new parameter color to their backend

Comment: thank you, but i have 3 status :D available :green , sold:red and booked in yellow .. is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yes! You can find that in the link I provided about class and style bindings, but I also added an example in the answer.

Comment: @sara97 Glad to have helped! I hope you continue to use and enjoy Vue, and be sure to post any more questions if needed!